# Use function declared below current function (allow circular dependency)?

Tags: c++, function, g++, dependencies

So C++ won't let me use a function physically above where I declare it (in other words, the function must be on a smaller line number than its use).  My problem is my functions all depend on at least one of the others.  In other words:

```
void funct1()
{
     if (something is true)
     {
         funct2();
     }
     else
          cout << someResult;
}


void funct2()
{
     if(something is true)
     {
         funct3();
     }
     else
          cout << someResult;
}

void funct3()
{
     if (something is true)
     {
         funct1();
     }
     else
          cout << someResult;
}
}
```

In other words, each function needs to call one of the others in some cases.  This will not work regardless of what order I put the functions in because at least one depends on something below it.  How do I make the compiler look below the current function when compiling (i.e. read everything then decide what is valid)  I am using g++ on CodeBlocks.

Comment: If all functions depend on each other, that's usually an indication of a design flaw, but there are forward declarations.

Comment: You need to forward declare funct1 and funct3 => http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/17-forward-declarations/

Comment: Also, look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration for a great overview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add some forward declarations before the function definitions:

```
void funct1();
void funct2();
void funct3();
```

This way, you can use the functions in any order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming you meant for the last function to be `funct3`. You can get away with using a single forward declaration:

```
void funct2();

void funct1() { if(something is true) { funct2(); } else cout << someResult; }

void funct3() { if(something is true) { funct1(); } else cout << someResult; }

void funct2() { if(something is true) { funct3(); } else cout << someResult; }
```

It just completes the cycle. `funct2 <- funct1 <- funct3 <- funct2`.

However, I'm highly suspicious of any code that has dependencies like this.

Comment: thanks, the reason for the dependencies is that I am creating a cascading loop of actions (one thing causes the next, some of which start another chain off)